# Difference between linux kernel and Ubuntu mainline kernel

Tags: kernel

As this  [wiki Ubuntu page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/FAQ) says:

> By definition the mainline kernel builds are made from virgin
>   unaltered mainline kernel sources and therefore do not, and should
>   not, include any Ubuntu patches or drivers. There are also no binary
>   drivers for these kernels.

I wonder what is the difference between an Ubuntu mainline kernel and a linux kernel?

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a brief answer.

Mainline kernels are just vanilla kernels from [kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/) packed as deb.

Ubuntu kernels are specially maintained by Canonical Kernel Team.

The team backports bug fixes and support of some new hardware from the latest mainline kernels, and also does other improvements.

Canonical and the community supports only the Ubuntu kernels. You can install the mainline ones at your own risk.

Comment: Where can you install the Ubuntu ones manually if need be?