# Installing 18.04 Kernel on 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, kernel, updates, 18.04

How can I install the latest Ubuntu kernel on Ubuntu 16.04? I have found a method to install the GENERIC kernel, but that's not what I want. I know this is probably a question people will call me an idiot for asking, but I'm having figuring it out and need some help.

Comment: What kernel do you want if not the 18.04 generic kernel ? mainline ? https://askubuntu.com/questions/764561/difference-between-linux-kernel-and-ubuntu-mainline-kernel See also https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds they maintain a ppa for mainline

Comment: That mainline one is the one I got, but it broke some programs compiled for Ubuntu. I want the kernel made for Ubuntu 18.04 itself so all programs compiled for Ubuntu will still work.

Comment: That sounds like the 18.04 generic kernel. You can download it from here as a .deb https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=linux-image-generic and then install it with dpkg. It may break packages as well and similar to running the mainline kernel, support would be poor as 18.04 has not been released and the 16.04 is not designed to support the 18.04 kernel. But it might work, sort of depends on your hardware.

Comment: I'm having some issues installing it. It says that it depends on linux-image-extra-4.15.0-12-generic but it's not installed. How could what I'm trying to install depend on itself?

EDIT: Ignore that, I just wasn't paying attention to what I was doing.